# Store docker command result in varaible in Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile

We are trying to store the container names in my Makefile but I see below error when executing the build, someone please advise. Thanks.

```
   .PHONY: metadata
metadata: .env1 
  docker pull IMAGE_NAME
  docker run  $IMAGE_NAME;
  ID:= $(shell docker ps --format '{{.Names}}')
  @echo ${ID}
  docker cp ${ID}:/app/.env .env2
```

Container names are not shown in  below "ID" Variable when executing the makefile from Jenkins

```
ID:= 
/bin/sh: ID:=: command not found
```

Comment: Please provide the FULL rule.  Without the context it's impossible to know what the problem is.  However, note that the command lines in the recipe of a rule are run _by the shell_ the are not run by make.  So you can't use make constructs (such as make variable assignment) in a recipe.

Comment: Please see above updated makefile code and error received after executing Makefile.Thanks.

Comment: I cannot tell what's happening based on this... please fix the formatting.

Comment: Please see above updated makefile code and error received after executing Makefile. I need to retreive the container names, I am using the same image is calling in multiple services parallel and when I use the particular name there is a conflict with other service with same container name so here I am not using name when running container but want to retreive the container names so that I can copy the whole container file structure on my host machine

Comment: Your problem is basically what I said in my first comment above; see David's answer below for full details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do in terms of pure Docker mechanics to simplify this.

You can specify an alternate command when you `docker run` an image: anything after the image name is taken as the image to run.  For instance, you can `cat` the file as the main container command, and replace everything you have above as:

```makefile
.PHONY: getmetadata
getmetadata: .env2
.env2: .env1
        docker run --rm \
          -e "ARTIFACTORY_USER=${ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_USR}" \
          -e "ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=${ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_PSW}" \
          --env-file .env1 \
          "${ARTIFACTDATA_IMAGE_NAME}" \
          cat /app/.env \
        > $@
```

(It is usually better to avoid `docker cp`, `docker exec`, and other imperative-type commands; it is fairly inexpensive and better practice to run a new container when you need to.)

If you can't do this, you can `docker run --name` your choice of names, and then use that container name in the `docker cp` option.

```makefile
.PHONY: getmetadata
getmetadata: .env2
.env2: .env1
        docker run --name getmetadata ...
        docker cp getmetadata:/app/.env $@
        docker stop getmetadata
        docker rm getmetadata
```

If you really can't avoid this at all, each line of the Makefile runs in a separate shell.  On the one hand this means you need to join together lines if you want variables from one line to be visible in a later line; on the other, it means you have normal shell functionality available and don't need to use the GNU Make `$(shell ...)` extension (which evaluates when the Makefile is loaded and not when you're running the command).

```makefile
.PHONY: getmetadata
getmetadata: .env2
.env2: .env1
        # Note here:
        # $$ escapes $ for the shell
        # Multiple shell commands joined together with && \
        # Beyond that, pure Bourne shell syntax
        ID=$$(docker run -d ...) && \
        echo "$$ID" && \
        docker cp "$$ID:/app/.env" "$@"
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe is not evaluated when the makefile is loaded, but it _IS_ evaluated before any command in the recipe is run.  So even if it appears in the last command in the recipe, it will be evaluated before the first command is run.